# Issue with pexpect match

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a `python-pexpect` code snippet something like this:

```
while True:
    master.sendline("show rsu-set all")
    status=master.expect(["[sS]nmp.*[ ]*=[ ]*[0-9].*[0-9]","Savari>>",TIMEOUT,EOF],4)
    if status == 0:
        old_slave_ip = master.match.group().split("=")[1]
        master.sendline("config rsu-set delete "+old_slave_ip)
        master.expect("Savari>>")

        master.sendline("config rsu-set commit")
        master.expect("Savari>>")
        continue
    elif status == 1:
        break
    else:
        print "Timed out or EOF reached"
        exit_flag = 1
        exit(1)
```

Actual output from the shell:

```
Savari>> show rsu-set all 

Mode                = master
SnmpSlaveIPAddress  = 192.168.20.204
SnmpSlaveIPAddress  = 192.168.20.210
```

Here, before configuring new `ip`s I'm trying to delete, old `ip`s. So I'm   trying to match the ip address and then send instruction to `delete` that `ip`.

So I'm expecting the `ip` using `"[sS]nmp.*[ ]*=[ ]*[0-9].*[0-9]"` and then extracting the `ip` using `split()` method.

I was expecting the `old_slave_ip` value to be `ip` address only. But it also has `SnmpSlaveIPAddress` of the next line which is causing some misbehavior.

The output of the script is like:

```
Savari>> show rsu-set all

Mode                = master
SnmpSlaveIPAddress  = 192.168.20.204
SnmpSlaveIPAddress  = 192.168.20.210

Savari>> config rsu-set delete  192.168.20.204

Savari>>

Savari>> SnmpSlaveIPAddress
          ^Command not found

Savari>> config rsu-set commit

Savari>> show rsu-set all

Mode                = master
SnmpSlaveIPAddress  = 192.168.20.210

Savari>> config rsu-set delete  master

Invalid value
```

This continues in an infinite loop.

When there is only one `ip` address the script works fine. This is happening only when there are more than one ip in the list.

Please help me out to figure this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it would be helpful if you create a dummy python script that prints *"actual output from the shell"* incrementally at random times and run this script using `pexpect` trying to extract ips. In other words, create [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your 'expect' matches only one address it gets something like :

```
SnmpSlaveIPAddress  = 192.168.20.204
```

but in case there more address it catches more than what you really wants, something like:

```
SnmpSlaveIPAddress  = 192.168.20.204
SnmpSlaveIPAddress  =
```

So, your 'old_slave_ip' gets the address, plus the part you don't want.
In order to get rid of that I would try :

```
old_slave_ip = master.match.group().split("=")[1].split('\n')[0]
```

That is to say, only what's on the first line of what was caught by expect. And it should work in both cases (only one address, and more)

Comment: but why is it matching second one...any idea??

Comment: I guess it isn't dealing with lines, but with a chunk of data. I agree with you, it is quite a silly thing ; as you might expect I struglled with it as well ;)